# Matlab outcome is different between online version and 2019a version

Tags: matlab

I have stacked bar codes that I want to see negative values below zero. When I use MATLAB online version I can get what I want but when I perform it on my computer it doesn't differentiate between positive and negative value. 
I am using MATLAB 2019a.

```
scaleaccretdecm(1:52, 1)=[0.024385606   0.022413488 0.044662561 0.003465332 0.020993959 0.032899477 0.030234633 0.049393371 0.045227192 0.042258106 0.065216925 0.060235394 0.050300704 0.059009665 0.044761431 0.032358603 0.012341471 0.019592291 0.040222551 0.029380475 0.037589868 0.046407316 0.077936607 0.107160264 0.096636333 0.0878621   0.108100764 0.075800066 0.118804893 0.108354917 0.121995114 0.145283354 0.156555518 0.175677074 0.201213601 0.220005439 0.167424693 0.183198114 0.188126781 0.199241433 0.229967391 0.232639002 0.228793215 0.228090775 0.229343472 0.217403674 0.237397605 0.247221671 0.260484612 0.292758388 0.28522593  0.269695308];
scaleaccretdecm(1:52, 2)=[-0.009871475  -0.005268862    0.001091759 0.034312917 0.029936851 0.042577605 0.052247005 0.035380186 0.032435718 0.074918233 0.038400657 0.024173677 0.058605382 0.049289806 0.052726973 0.059984301 0.078675061 0.075863711 0.053860121 0.062903069 0.064338411 0.078853407 0.052406498 0.023773216 0.037638943 0.053554811 0.02469932  0.045283892 0.026318071 0.030571141 0.030920266 0.020580842 0.004162456 -0.002937019    -0.023951657    -0.036207684    -0.05364969 -0.06978204 -0.049198249    -0.047269172    -0.042161151    -0.060016701    -0.042602654    -0.057791123    -0.050319653    -0.048266361    -0.04358329 -0.047806285    -0.031104006    -0.053715053    -0.03760559 -0.024190423];
scaleaccretdecm(1:52, 3)=[-0.011056757  -0.006954471    -0.002173208    0.009260237 0.00265849  0.003678591 0.006136322 -0.004435098    -0.008606409    0.002194055 -0.011360281    -0.014624702    -0.004002074    -0.009218405    -0.006049953    -8.56E-05   0.004971094 0.004898834 -0.00464586 0.000610642 0.000701145 0.004663761 -0.004330913    -0.017295049    -0.01253931 -0.007307185    -0.019971941    -0.011727831    -0.017468372    -0.015775705    -0.015876961    -0.021131038    -0.029309852    -0.029977501    -0.039566658    -0.04216126 -0.041484996    -0.043002834    -0.038862395    -0.037267353    -0.034064608    -0.039055899    -0.032824281    -0.037671632    -0.034290661    -0.034069499    -0.03312865 -0.034882352    -0.031628822    -0.038194886    -0.030256354    -0.027014841];

figure;
hold on; 
t = datetime(2001,1,5) + calweeks(1:52);
bar(t,scaleaccretdecm(1:52, 1:3),.99,"stacked");
hold on;
bar(t,-scaleaccretdecm(1:52, 1:3),.001,"stacked"); %legend(txt(16:18),'Location','southoutside');
ylim([-.5 .5]);
hold on;
saveas(gcf,'AccumReturns.png');
hold off;
```

[image: MATLAB online]

[image: MATLAB2019a]

Comment: This difference appears to be because MATLAB Online is using R2019b. (It doesn't explain why there's a difference between R2019a and R2019b though...)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Question is OK. In online (likely 2019b) the stacked bars are "stacked" on the direction of their sign, and it seems that in older versions (I can test 2018b) they stack the absolute value of the input (which is obviously not correct)

Comment: As an aside: `hold on` is ON after mentioning it *one*. There is no need to chuck it three times into the same figure, once switched on, it will remain on until explicitly switched off, using `hold off`. Note that having the axis holding doesn't matter to following code, so usually there's no need to switch holding off either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [MATLAB Release Notes for R2019b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?category=graphics&rntext=&startrelease=R2019b&endrelease=R2019b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=) you can read:

> The `bar` and `barh` functions have these improvements:
>
> - Stacked groups of bars display negative bars below zero, rather than overlapping the bars.

That is, this is a change introduced in R2019b (MATLAB Online always uses the latest version). Thus, if you want to recreate these graphs on your desktop, you will have to upgrade your version of MATLAB.